# asp.net databinding string is passed to function but runtime occurs

Tags: asp.net

I'm using a code-behind function (called TestFx) in my binding expression. I'm passing a string and the function accepts a string but I still get a runtime error saying invalid args.

But if I change the method to accept an object and inspect the value, "it's a string!"
Can someone please explain?

-rod

```
   ProductDescription:
                <asp:Label ID="ProductDescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# TestFx(Eval("ProductDescription")) %>' />
                <br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `Eval` is `object`. As you've noticed, you can either change the signature of your method to accept an object, or you can typecast the result of `Eval("ProductDescription")` to a string:

```
<asp:Label ID="ProductDescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# TestFx(Eval("ProductDescription").ToString()) %>' />
```

Comment: or if you know for a fact the item will be a string you can just cast it instead of calling `ToString`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to handle repeater control [ItemDataBound](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c12065) event. It's more suitable if ItemTemplate elements require complex decoration